# jquery lavalamp and autoscroll easing problem (conflict)

Tags: jquery, autoscroll, lavalamp

I have got a problem and am really hoping you guys can help.

http://ontwikkelomgeving.wijzijnblits.nl/primawonen/
Here you can find a website that i am currently creating.

As you can see the autoscroll works (called het laatste aanbod).
This uses the easing.min.js plugin. 
At the navigation i use lavalamp, however this does not work right now.

The problem lies in the easing plugin. If i use an older version of this plugin, lavalamp works. Great you would think, but then the autoscroll script does not work.
How can i make it so that both will work?!

I am seriously stuck on this one, and hope that you guys can help me.

thnx in advance

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem and I just figured out a way to make it work, add the following lines above everything else in lavalamp.js

```
jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{ 
    bouncein: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c - jQuery.easing["bounceout"](x, d - t, 0, c, d) + b;
    },    
    backout: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s = 1.70158;
        return c * ((t = t / d - 1) * t * ((s + 1) * t + s) + 1) + b;
    }

});
```

And remove the easing plugin. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with two conflicting jquery libraries and found this
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

This method worked for me - the order of the scripts is important:

```
      <script src="secondary-jquery-script.js"></script>
   <script src="jquery-original-script.js"></script>
   <script>
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

     // Here comes the part that needs jquery-Original-script.js - jQuery via $j(...)
     $j(document).ready(function(){
       $j("div").hide();
     });

     // and here comes the part that needs the secondary script
     $('someid').hide();
   </script>
```